# AlarmManager Triggers before second interval completes

Tags: java, android, alarmmanager

I have written an Alarm code that runs every day at 5:22 am. The code works fine for the first interval, but it triggers before 24 hours for second interval.

I have added the Alarm code in `onCreate()` method of the MainActivity, the code runs perfect for the first interval but after the first interval if I open the MainActivity the Alarm triggers again and keeps on triggering when I open the MainActivity. For example if I open the MainActivity twice the alarm triggers twice.

I have also referred to few solutions here but they didn't work like [marmor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13530205/92487).

I have also tried to check if the alarm was set using FLAG_NO_CREATE flag but still it does not work.

Below is my code.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 11111, intent, 0);

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
        //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
        calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
            AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent); //1000 * 60 * 1440

}
```

I'm logging the time when the service runs into a text file.

Edit :

The target sdk version is 22

And according to kolombo's suggestion I have checked the dates and checked whether my if statement is executed. The if statement is executed and I get tomorrow's date with same time.

I'm using Moto E for developing the app.

I have uploaded the project files [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw1oYLNzdr8pYUNCWDNnQWw5VkU/view?usp=sharing) on google drive.

Comment: I suppose your if statement doesnt work. Did you debug this dates? You need more dates control, more debug information in the LogCat and you will see whats wrong with it. Convert dates to normal format and compare it.

Comment: what's target SDK for the project (in Manifest)?

Comment: And dont use clone, its not neccessary. 'if(calSet.getTimeInMillis() <= Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())'

Comment: Target sdk version is 22

Comment: @kolombo The if condition is getting executed, just checked in log cat by adding Log.i in the if condition but still the Alarm triggers early.

Comment: @Searock Try this. https://codeshare.io/9pMkd and tell me whats the dates in LogCat?

Comment: @kolombo the output is NextDay: 3 September - 07:02 and Now Day: 2 September - 07:02

Comment: So, all dates works fine for all activity runs and its not the point. Ok... So, its AlarmManager. Try to set it for one shot, not repeating, for example.  you need to try some variants, its debug, its always the same... I will try after a sleep, if you do not find the solution.

Comment: I posted an answer. Did you try? Did you solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return **START_NOT_STICKY** from your onStartCommand function on the Service. Or you must stop it after the job will be complete. Or you can use IntentService instead of Service. Alarm works fine.

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    try{
        commitToFile("Start");
    }catch (Exception e){}
    try{
        commitToFile("End");
    }catch (Exception e){}
    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}
```

You returned 0, thats START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY. When your alarm fires at the first time your service starting and run. And when you restart applicaton, your service restarts too, because you did not stop it. If you return START_NOT_STICKY - service will not be restarting. Or if you use IntentService, this service do the job and finished self automaticaly.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. It was very helpful for me. As an appreciation I will offer you a bounty of 200.

Comment: @Searock You are welcome :-) It was not difficult for me. And thanks for your bounty :-)

Comment: well you can reward an existing answer with a bounty can you? @Searock can you confirm with the bounty help on meta? you need to manually click the bounty next to the answer

Comment: I have done it in the past where I have rewarded bounty on someone else answer, so whats wrong if I award it to my own question. There is an option which says reward an existing answer. And the answer has really helped me to a great extend also the user has gone to a great extend to help me. :)

Answer (score 1):

Whenever your MainActivity starts onCreate() is called and thus you are ending up with the multiple instances of your Alarm Notifications.

AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ServiceReceiver.class);

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 11111, intent, 0);

Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 11);
calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

if(calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0){
    //Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
    calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}

alarmMgr.cancel(alarmIntent);
alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(),
        AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent); //1000 * 60 * 1440
```

put the above code inside a `if` condition and do save the result in SharedPreferences (Ex: calSet) when you are again onCreate called just get the value from getSharedPreferences and compare with the calNow.